# Delete all characters in a string by sequentially in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button

I want to delete characters in a string every time an event happens (button click) in Javascript.

for example :

```
str = "world";
```

the word would change in each step as follows :

- "orld"
- "rld"
- "ld"
- "d"
- ""

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `String.slice(N)` to remove the first `N` characters from a string

Here what you can do:

```html
<button id="my_button">WORLD</button>
```

```js
document.querySelector("#my_button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.innerText = this.innerText.slice(1)
});
```

Comment: @Flutterish changed it :)

Answer (score 0):

**You could use This Function**

```
function deleteString(value){
   return value.substring(1);
} 
str = deleteString(str)
```